# Make a Cancelled Droppable element Droppable again

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a few elements which are droppable. i made them droppable in the following way

```
function makeDraggable(id){
                console.log("inside draggable");
              $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
                    helper: "clone",
                    cursor: 'move'
                });
          }
```

Then i made it undraggable by cancel

```
function makeUndraggable(){
            console.log("inside undraggable");

            $( ".draggable" ).draggable({ 
                cancel: ".draggable" 
                });
          }
```

But now when i call the draggable function again, it wont make it draggable again.

I was previously using jquery-ui-1.7 and cancel was not working with it. So i moved to jquery-ui-1.12.1, cancel did work but now i cant undo cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just update your first function to clear the cancel parameter:

```
function makeDraggable(id){
    console.log("inside draggable");
    $( ".draggable" ).draggable({
        helper: "clone",
        cursor: 'move',
        cancel: ''
    });
}
```